# Website Got Hacked - Fixed - Now Cannot Activate Theme

Tags: ftp, hacked

My wordpress site got hacked, I fixed the problem but had to delete the TwentyFifteen theme (the one that was hacked). The theme I was originally using was different, but the hackers hacked the TwentyFifteen theme. When I deleted the theme, I went back to the wordpress dashboard and see this:

[image]

As you can see it's not recognizing any theme and I can't activate them. Also the Homepage is blank. Any ideas on how to activate a theme via FTP?

Thanks

Comment: If a core theme was hacked I would contact with WordPress Security Team to report it. Please, do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue 1:** Look at your dashboard; you're not logged in as an administrator, and as a result you don't have the privileges and can't activate themes or plugins.

With adminer or phpmyadmin, check your `wp_usermeta` table for your user and be sure the `wp_capabilities` key is for an admin: `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}`

Or, add a new admin via SQL:

```
INSERT INTO `*yourdatabasename*`.`wp_users` (`ID`, `user_login`, `user_pass`, `user_nicename`, `user_email`, `user_url`, `user_registered`, `user_activation_key`, `user_status`, `display_name`) VALUES ('999999', '*yourusername*', MD5('*password*'), '*yourfullname*', '*youremail*', '*http://example.com*', '2016-01-01 00:00:00', '', '0', '*yourfullname');

INSERT INTO `*yourdatabasename*`.`wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (NULL, '999999', 'wp_capabilities', 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}');
```

Replace `*examples*` with user name, real name, password (in plain text), etc. The `user_id` is set to 999999 to avoid collisions with existing user IDs.

**Issue 2:** Be sure you have carefully followed [FAQ - My Site Was Hacked - WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked). You may not have done a complete job cleaning the hack. Then take a look at the recommended security measures in [Hardening WordPress - WordPress Support](https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/) and [Brute Force Attacks - WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Brute_Force_Attacks)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I'll read those through. That is the administrator account so not sure what happened there. Any ideas how I can regain access through the backend?

Comment: Added some details; you need to use adminer or phpmyadmin to take a look at the database.